# Avatar is always null

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Am trying to attach a image/file to a user using the $attachOne relation. I can't seem to get the file uploaded from the component. Here is a piece of my code:

Model:

```
public $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|between:6,255|email|unique:users',
        'avatar'   => 'nullable|image|max:4000',
        'username' => 'required|between:2,255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required:create|between:4,255|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|between:4,255',
    ];

    public $attachOne = [
        'avatar' => \System\Models\File::class
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'surname',
        'login',
        'avatar',
        'username',
        'email',
        'telegram',
        'phone',
        'skype',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation'
    ];
```

Component:

```
 public function onUpdate()
    {
        if (!$user = $this->user()) {
            return;
        }

        if (Input::hasFile('avatar')) {
            $user->avatar = Input::file('avatar');
        }


        $user->fill(post());           
        $user->save();
        return $redirect;

}
```

Piece of default.htm code:

```
{{ form_ajax('onUpdate', { model: user,files: true  }) }}
 <input type="file" name="avatar">
```

Comment: can you share your site-url or which October build(version) you are using ?

Comment: Bug: `!$user = $this->user()` is assigning `$user`, not testing its value.  Use `==` or `===` to test.  Also, `$user` is not defined there anyway so your test will never work ... Probably you need `$user` as a parameter to `onUpdate()`?

Comment: this is not a bug @Don'tPanic its assignment and check, as `$user = $this->user()` will first assign value to `$user`  and suppose user is not logged in then it will return `null`  so final comparison will be if user is logged `!{user-model}` so its result will be `false`  and if not logged in then `!null` so its `true` and function will `return`not executing further

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `$user->avatar` after you're executing `fill()` method. Also, you need to save file name to DB, not file itself:

```
$user->avatar = request()->avatar->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: did not help =(

Comment: даже если назначу любое значение $user->avatar , на следующей строке делаю die c выводом user, и там avatar=null =(

Comment: @zoinx2012 looks fine. Please update you question with results of `dd(request()->all())` placed in the `onUpdate` method and please show the whole form. In this case, we will be able to help you.